# Numpy problem with big numbers, computation of eigenvalues and determinant

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I have this code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import exp


def foo(a,b):
    return np.array([[exp(-2*b*a), 0,-exp(b*a)/3 + exp(-2*b*a)/3],
                    [0, exp(-2*b*a), 0],
                    [-exp(b*a)/3 + exp(-2*b*a)/3,0, 10*exp(4*b*a)/9 - 2*exp(b*a)/9 + exp(-2*b*a)/9]])


a_s = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
b_s = np.linspace(0.1, 5, 100)

store_det = np.zeros((len(a_s), len(b_s)))

for i, b in enumerate(b_s):
    for j, a in enumerate(a_s):
        store_det[i,j] = np.linalg.det(foo(a,b))
        
print(f'max: {np.max(store_det)} \t min: {np.min(store_det)}')


store_det_by_eigen = np.zeros((len(a_s), len(b_s)))

for i, b in enumerate(b_s):
    for j, a in enumerate(a_s):
        w,v = np.linalg.eig(foo(a,b))
        store_det_by_eigen[i,j] = w[0]*w[1]*w[2]

print(f'max: {np.max(store_det_by_eigen)} \t min: {np.min(store_det_by_eigen)}')
```

The determinant of this equation should be one for every real value of `a` and `b`.

Given that this yields a 3x3 Array, I would like to compute the eigenvalues and use them in a calculation. The product of the eigenvalues should be equal to the determinant. However, for instance, for `a=10` and `b=5` the product is no longer 1.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe you need more precission? Try using `dtype=np.float128` when declaring the array to store eigenvalues: `store_det_by_eigen = np.zeros((len(a_s), len(b_s)), dtype=np.float128)`

Comment: Did it with `dtype=np.longdouble`. Had to switch to `scipy` for both determinant and eigvalues calculation. It did not solve the problem, the differences are still quite substantial

Comment: 'certain values'?  expect vague suggestions with such a vague description of the problem.

Comment: @hpaulj I have addressed the "vague" description. Please do let me know if it should be further improved.

Comment: In general I don't like to see code with 'print' statements without seeing to actual results for some test cases.  If I'm reading the question on my computer (instead of phone) I might copy-n-paste the code and run some cases on my pwn.  And add diagnostic prints.  How big are the 'errors'? Where do numbers blow up? etc

Answer (score 2):

On top of @ev-br I would stress that the eigenvalue algorithms can be a lot more numerically unstable (to widely different eigenvalue magnitudes) if they are based on exponentiation. I don't know which is used by numpy to be honest, but it seems to break down when your determinant becomes the product of a tiny eigenvalue and a large one.

Alternatively you could use a high precision library such as [mpmath](https://mpmath.org/doc/0.18/matrices.html#the-eigenvalue-problem). For your example:

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy import exp
from mpmath import mp
mp.dps = 63

def foo(a,b):
    return np.array([[exp(-2*b*a), 0,-exp(b*a)/3 + exp(-2*b*a)/3],
                    [0, exp(-2*b*a), 0],
                    [-exp(b*a)/3 + exp(-2*b*a)/3,0, 10*exp(4*b*a)/9 - 2*exp(b*a)/9 + exp(-2*b*a)/9]])


a_s = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
b_s = np.linspace(0.1, 5, 100)

store_det = np.zeros((len(a_s), len(b_s)))

for i, b in enumerate(b_s):
    for j, a in enumerate(a_s):
        store_det[i,j] = np.linalg.det(foo(a,b))
        
print(f'max: {np.max(store_det)} \t min: {np.min(store_det)}')


store_det_by_eigen = np.zeros((len(a_s), len(b_s)))

for i, b in enumerate(b_s):
    for j, a in enumerate(a_s):
        mat = mp.matrix(foo(a,b))
        w,_ = mp.eig(mat)
        store_det_by_eigen[i,j] = w[0]*w[1]*w[2]

print(f'max: {np.max(store_det_by_eigen)} \t min: {np.min(store_det_by_eigen)}')
#prints
#max: 1.0000000000000036     min: 0.9999999999999929
#max: 1.0000000000000004     min: 0.9999999999999994
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Is `mpmath` still maintained?

Comment: Maybe this link is more upto date: https://mpmath.org/doc/current/matrices.html?highlight=eigenvalue%20problem

Comment: @R.Smith my bad I pointed at an old version doc, this was my first hit with Google. And yeah mpmath looks kind of maintained: last release is a few months old, and it is compatible with Python 3.11

Answer (score 1):

With a,b = 10, 5, your matrix has entries of the order of exp(50) and exp(-50). Not very surprisingly, computatuons lose precision, as you simply cannot distinguish 1+exp(-50) from 1 (even though exp(-50) is different from zero).

FWIW, trying extended precision is rarely an answer. You should probably rethink your approach, staring from reasons you need these large/small entries and what you actually compute.

Answer (score 0):

So for one case, the eigenvalues are:

```
In [43]: np.linalg.eig(foo(1,1))
Out[43]: 
(array([ 0.12297068, 60.08795038,  0.13533528]),
 array([[-0.9998969 ,  0.01435956,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
        [-0.01435956, -0.9998969 ,  0.        ]]))
```

and product close to 1:

```
In [44]: np.prod(_[0])
Out[44]: 0.9999999999999974
```

For a cited problem case:

```
In [45]: np.linalg.eig(foo(10,5))
Out[45]: 
(array([3.72007598e-44, 8.02885974e+86, 3.72007598e-44]),
 array([[ 1.00000000e+00, -2.15252879e-66,  0.00000000e+00],
        [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00],
        [ 0.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00]]))

In [46]: np.prod(_[0])
Out[46]: 1.1111111111111112
```

Not nearly so close - but still in the neighborboods.  This isn't surprising since the eigvalues are either very small or very large.

look at the 2 arrays:

```
In [50]: foo(1,1)
Out[50]: 
array([[ 0.13533528,  0.        , -0.86098218],
       [ 0.        ,  0.13533528,  0.        ],
       [-0.86098218,  0.        , 60.07558577]])

In [51]: foo(10,5)
Out[51]: 
array([[ 3.72007598e-44,  0.00000000e+00, -1.72823518e+21],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  3.72007598e-44,  0.00000000e+00],
       [-1.72823518e+21,  0.00000000e+00,  8.02885974e+86]])
```

That middle row (or column) is nearly all 0s.